# Generating two non-overlapping colorspaces

Tags: matplotlib, colormap, viridis

I wish to simultaneously scatterplot two distributions on the same plot, so that I can see at a glance each distribution, as well as the relationship between them.

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html shows:

[image]

... so if I take a chunk out of Viridis and a chunk out of Plasma, I should be good to go.

But then I'm losing the full dynamic range. I've asked whether this is "fixable" here: [Restore full dynamic range to a subsection of a colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541245/restore-full-dynamic-range-to-a-subsection-of-a-colormap)

I'm surprised I can't find literature on this task, as it seems like a piece of machinery that would find many uses.

Is it possible to generate a chunk of (say) Viridis, and restore the dynamic range?

Or failing that, Is it possible to start from scratch and construct two symmetrical paths through a suitable "perceptually uniform" colourspace?

Comment: Why do you not want to use any of the diverging colormaps?